# OpenCV: Ordering a contours by area (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

The OpenCV library provides a function that returns a set of contours for a binary (thresholded) image. The contourArea() can be applied to find associated areas.

Is the list of contours out outputted by findContours() ordered in terms of area by default? If not, **does anyone know of a cv2 function that orders a list of contours by area?**

Please provide responses in Python, not C.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27156873/5008845) can be helful. You just need to change the `greater` function to compare areas.

Comment: To partially address my question, the findContours() apparently outputs a list topologically ordered in terms of (x,y) coordinates (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693312/opencv-findcontours-how-contours-are-ordered). The second, bold part of the question still stands.

Comment: I was addressing the _bold_ part. You just need to sort your contours using a custom sorting function. I can't give you Python code, but it's pretty straightforward to modify `greater` comparing `contourArea()` of the two contours.

Comment: The last part of the post was meant for clarification, not to knock your answer. Hoping for an answer that allows for a comparison of the entire array, rather than a pair of contours, although I suppose the leap from comparison to a sorting function that uses the comparison isn't terribly difficult. My apologies if I'm missing something here.

Comment: my response was for clarification, too :D

Comment: Just saw the sort method being applied on the bottom of that linked post. Looks like I have what I need.

Comment: If you make it work, post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 16):

Use `sorted` and sort by the area key:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(boolImage.astype(np.uint8), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]  
cntsSorted = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))
```

Answer (score 13):

```
image, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

**cnt** gives you an ordered list of contours in increasing order w.r.t area.

You can find the area of contour by index:

```
area = cv2.contourArea(cnt[index])
```

index can be 1,2,3.....,len(cnts)

For accessing the largest area contour:

```
cnt[reverse_index]
```

give reverse_index as **-1**

For second largest give reverse_index as **-2** and so on.

The above can also be achieved with:

```
cnt = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
```

so cnt[1]  gives the largest contour cnt[2] second largest and so on.

Comment: if I have two contours or more and I need to sum them. please, help me how?? for example: cnts = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]  # get largest five contour area

Comment: area = sum([cv2.contourArea(cnt)  for cnt in sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]])

Comment: I tried to work {{{x, y, w, h = [cv2.boundingRect(n) for n in cnts ]}}} similar yours but give me error: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: [cv2.boundingRect(n) for n in cnts] => it would give a list of [(x,y,w,h), (x,y,w,h).....]. Thats why its showing the error.

Comment: Shouldn't that be cnt[0] for the largest and cnt[1] for the second largest since we start indexing at 0? If not, what's at index 0?

Comment: "index can be 1,2,3.....,len(cnts)" thats why cnt[1] else it would have been cnt[0]