# Given an image with several bounding boxes, how do I highlight only those bounding boxes that are completely inside another bounding box?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour, bounding-box

I don't want to highlight bounding boxes that are either partly overlapping with others, or not overlapping with any other box. I tried to do this by detecting contours:

```
import cv2

# Read input image
img = cv2.imread('image.png')

# Convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply threshold
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find contours and hierarchy
cnts, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2:]

# Draw all contours with green color for testing
cv2.drawContours(img, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0))

# Hierarchy Representation in OpenCV
# So each contour has its own information regarding what hierarchy it is, 
# who is its child, who is its parent etc. 
# OpenCV represents it as an array of four values : [Next, Previous, First_Child, Parent]

# Iterate contours and hierarchy:
for c, h in zip(cnts, hier[0]):
    # Check if contour has one partent and one at least on child:
    if (h[3] >= 0) and (h[2] >= 0):
        # Get the partent from the hierarchy
        hp = hier[0][h[3]]

        # Check if the parent has a parent:
        if hp[3] >= 0:
            # Get bounding rectange
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

            # Draw red rectange for testing
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), thickness=1)


# Show result for testing
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But its selecting every contour in the image. For example, if this is the original image:

[image]

Then this is the result I get when running the above code:

[image]

How do I, firstly, detect only bounding boxes in this image, and secondly, highlight only those bounding boxes that are completely, 100% inside another bounding box?

Comment: you should see about getting the data that was used to draw those boxes in the first place. extracting them from the drawn image seems kinda silly to me.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Sort the bounding boxes in increasing order of area  using `cv2.contourArea`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669415/opencv-ordering-a-contours-by-area-python).

Step 2 - For loop - starting with the smallest bounding boxes - Check if a given box's intersection area with bigger boxes = area of given box. If yes, then it is 100% inside other bigger box.

For example we can convert a bounding box into a mask like this:

```
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=np.float32)
(x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in bounding_box]
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 1.
```

Then to get the area of intersection of two masks:

```
mask1_f = mask1.flatten()
mask2_f = mask2.flatten()
intersection = np.sum(mask1_f * mask2_f)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a box to be completely inside another box, each vertex of the box should be inside the bigger box. You can use a nested for loop to filter the boxes to check if all coordinates of the box2 is within range of box1.

```
collided_boxes = []
for box1 in boxes:
    for box2 in boxes:
        if box1 != box2:
            if (box1[0] < box2[0] < box1[2] and box1[1] < box2[1] < box1[3]) and (box1[0] < box2[2] < box1[2] and box1[1] < box2[1] < box1[3]) and (box1[0] < box2[2] < box1[2] and box1[1] < box2[3] < box1[3]) and (box1[0] < box2[0] < box1[2] and box1[1] < box2[3] < box1[3]): 
                if box2 not in collided_boxes:
                    collided_boxes.append(box2)
```

In above, I gave values of the coordinates of the two extreme corners of the box which is [(min x value, min y value) and (max x value, max y value)] as: box[0] = min x value, box[1] = min y value, box[2] = max x value, box[3] = max y value

Answer (score 0):

`import numpy as np


def IOU(box1, box2):
    """
    Computes intersection over union (IoU) between two bounding boxes.

    Parameters:
        box1 (numpy array): bounding box coordinates in [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax] format
        box2 (numpy array): bounding box coordinates in [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax] format

    Returns:
        iou (float): intersection over union (IoU) between the two boxes
    """
    # Find intersection coordinates
    x1 = np.maximum(box1[0], box2[0])
    y1 = np.maximum(box1[1], box2[1])
    x2 = np.minimum(box1[2], box2[2])
    y2 = np.minimum(box1[3], box2[3])

    # Find intersection area
    intersection = np.maximum(0, x2 - x1) * np.maximum(0, y2 - y1)

    # Find union area
    area_box1 = (box1[2] - box1[0]) * (box1[3] - box1[1])
    area_box2 = (box2[2] - box2[0]) * (box2[3] - box2[1])
    union = area_box1 + area_box2 - intersection

    if area_box1 > area_box2:
        max_area = 0
    else:
        max_area = 1

    # Compute IoU
    iou = intersection / union

    return iou, max_area



def ignore_inner_bboxes(bboxes):
    """
    This function takes a list of bounding boxes and removes any bounding boxes that are completely
    contained within another bounding box.

    Parameters:
        - bboxes: A list of bounding boxes in the format [x, y, w, h]

    Returns:
        A new list of bounding boxes with any inner bounding boxes removed.
    """
    filtered_bboxes = []
    ignore_list = []
    for i, bbox in enumerate(bboxes):
        is_innerbox_fount = False
        if bbox in ignore_list:
            continue
        for j, other_bbox in enumerate(bboxes):
            if i == j:
                continue
            iou, large_box = IOU(bbox, other_bbox)
            if iou > 0.10:
                is_innerbox_fount = True
                if large_box == 0:
                    if bbox not in filtered_bboxes:
                        filtered_bboxes.append(bbox)
                    if other_bbox in filtered_bboxes:
                        filtered_bboxes.remove(other_bbox)
                    ignore_list.append(other_bbox)
                else:
                    if other_bbox not in filtered_bboxes:
                        filtered_bboxes.append(bbox)
                    if bbox in filtered_bboxes:
                        filtered_bboxes.remove(bbox)
                    ignore_list.append(bbox)
        if not is_innerbox_fount:
            filtered_bboxes.append(bbox)
    return filtered_bboxes



bboxes = [[50, 50, 100, 100], [80, 80, 120, 120], [100, 100, 120, 120], [110, 110, 125, 125], [120, 120, 200, 200]]
filtered_bboxes = ignore_inner_bboxes(bboxes)
print(filtered_bboxes)`